# Is there a name for an answer to a question that is the subject in the question?

Tags: subjects

For example: Why is the Sun hot?  Because it's the Sun. Why is the grass green?  Because it's grass.

Comment: Do you mean like in "Why do n00bs ask daft questions?"

Comment: This is just sarcasm - the answer isn't really in the question.  The answer to "why is the sun hot" is "because it's undergoing nuclear fusion".

Comment: Your examples are inadequate.  The sun is hot for other reasons (hydrogen, explosions, etc) and an astronomer can explain it better than I.  Grass is green because it has a green pigment called chlorophyll.

Comment: Please rephrase your questions and give good examples.

Comment: Ughhh. These questions should just be deleted. Why even bother??

Comment: I think you're really asking, "Is the sun the sun?" But let's turn that into a statement: "The sun is the sun." The logical positivists argue that no proposition, other than a tautology, can possibly be anything more than a probable hypothesis. So that statement is cognitively verifiable or--the truth.

Answer (score 3):

You might call this a **[tautology](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3A+tautology):**

> the saying of the same thing twice in different words, generally
>   considered to be a fault of style (e.g., they arrived one after the
>   other in succession ).
>
> **synonyms:** pleonasm, repetition, reiteration, redundancy, superfluity, duplication
>
> *"avoid such tautology as "let's all work together, everyone, as a team" by saying simply "let's work together""*
>
> a phrase or expression in which the same thing is said twice in
>   different words.

See also: [circular reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reasoning)

Answer (score 2):

**self evident:**

> evident without proof or reasoning (Merriam Webster)
>
> clear or obvious without needing any proof or explanation: Solutions
>   which seem self-evident to humans are often beyond the grasp of
>   computers (Cambridge)

Answer (score 2):

These are **[circular](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/circular) answers**. *Circular* meaning "*referring back to itself*" or "*leading back to itself*".

Circular answers are an example of [circular reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reasoning) or logic: the answer follows from the question, but the question also follows from the answer.